# How do I get resolvconf to regenerate resolv.conf after I change /etc/network/interfaces?

Tags: server, dns, resolv.conf

After updating `/etc/network/interfaces` with something very similar to below, how do I get `/etc/resolv.conf` to update?  I tried (as root) `resolver -u`, `service networking restart` but they didn't work. I also fixed the symlink for `resolv.conf` and tried `resolver -u` again. Finally in frustration I rebooted, which did fix the problem by rebuilding `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Ubuntu 12.04, 64bit server, all the latest patches installed.

Example `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.3.3
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.3.1
    dns-search example.com
    dns-nameservers 192.168.3.45 192.168.8.10
```

Answer (score 128, accepted):

`service networking restart` is not always a reliable way of down-upping all interfaces.

The `resolvconf -u` command only updates `resolv.conf` from resolvconf's own database. You need to update the database.

To update the database you have to call resolvconf with the `-a` or `-d` option. That happens behind the scenes when you run ifup or ifdown. So, normally, as with any other change to `/etc/network/interfaces`, to activate changes to the dns-* options you have to ifdown the interface in question and ifup it again. Or you can reboot.

If you want to make changes to an interface without ifdownupping it (perhaps because you are administering the machine remotely and happen to be connected via that interface, natch) then you can achieve the same result by running resolvconf directly from the command line. This requires a bit more knowledge of resolvconf's semantics. Assume the relevant /e/n/i stanza is

```
iface IIII FFFF static
    address ...
    ...
    dns-nameservers X.X.X.X Y.Y.Y.Y
    dns-search SSSS
```

where FFFF is an address family ("inet" or "inet6").

To activate these dns-* options you run resolvconf as follows (yes, with newlines in the string piped to resolvconf).

```
echo "nameserver X.X.X.X
nameserver Y.Y.Y.Y
search SSSS" | sudo resolvconf -a IIII.FFFF
```

For the stanza given in the question this would be the following.

```
echo "nameserver 192.168.3.45
nameserver 192.168.8.10
search example.com" | sudo resolvconf -a eth0.inet
```

Consult the resolvconf(8) manual page and the resolvconf package README file (/usr/share/doc/resolvconf/README.gz) for more information.

Comment: "Don't do "service networking restart"; that's not a reliable way of down-upping all interfaces." Works fine for me. Good to know the clean way of doing it though.

Comment: If you shouldn't do "service networking restart" can I suggest you don't put it in the first line of this question? When hurriedly looking for a solution, the first thing I did was copy and paste the first command I saw.

Comment: @RobinWinslow +1 for making my day

Comment: This answer is from the person himself who has developed `resolvconf`  :)

Comment: To restart/reread `/etc/network/interfaces`, you can do that : `ifdown eth0 && ifup eth0` ; it works even in a remote ssh session.

Comment: does not work for me.  The second nameserver (which is needed for `dnsmasq`) is ignored (for an network manager auto interface).  So somewhere there are some bits missing what to do in this case.

Comment: If dhcp settings were used on an interface such as eth0 in /etc/network/interfaces, one could initiate dhcp client and re-request IP address by running dhclient -r eth0; dhclient eth0

Comment: @Pierre-Damien Unless there is a mistake like in `sudo ifdown eth0 && ifup eth0` (missing `sudo` on second command). Still there are more reliable ways.

Comment: `Failed to restart networking.service: Unit networking.service is masked.`

Answer (score 33):

Although the manpage isn't installed by default it's documented via the update scripts option, just run:

```
sudo resolvconf -u
```

Comment: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/resolvconf.8.html

Comment: Old answer, but just to confirm, this works in Ubuntu v20, no need to install other packages, just resolvconf.

Comment: Command not found (Ubuntu)

Comment: does not work for me on ubuntu 20.04
my /etc/resolv.conf is still not updated

Comment: deprecated in or before 2023

Answer (score 9):

For those of you managing your servers remotely you can:

1. update the `dns-nameservers` line in `/etc/network/interfaces`
2. `# ifdown eth01; ifup eth01`

Notice that this has to be on one line divided with ; (the linux command line separator).
You should not even lose your current connection.  The exception is making a typo in the interfaces file.  If this happens `ifup` will fail and you will have to have physical access or another `ethxx` connection.

Answer (score 4):

`service resolvconf restart` will regenerate `/etc/resolv.conf` file without much fuss.

Comment: I get `Failed to restart resolvconf.service: Unit resolvconf.service not found.`

Comment: command completed however not regenerated `/etc/resolv.conf` on ubuntu server 14.04

Comment: On Ubuntu 18.04, there was no fuss, like you said, but the file was not regenerated either... Be aware of this, make a backup before following instructions.

Comment: first of all make sure thaat `apt install resolvconf`

Answer (score 3):

Simple answer :

Just install resolvconf. `apt install resolvconf`

After that, `ifup eth0` updates the dns in `etc/resolv.conf`, according to the  `dns-nameservers` line in `/etc/network/interfaces`.

Comment: unknown interface. Everybody really knows how to obfuscate the details here ... I think we should aim to containerize all the commands. Full script for each, no prose.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is similar to the one above but uses the questions example configuration to answer the question.  Plus this explains why both commands are necessary.

Edit `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.3.3
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.3.1
    dns-search example.com
    dns-nameserver 192.168.3.45
    dns-nameserver 192.168.8.10
```

These changes will not take place unless you reboot or reload the configuration file:

In order to update the interfaces file live it is necessary to run the following command:

```
echo "nameserver 192.168.3.45
nameserver 192.168.8.10
search example.com" | sudo resolvconf -a eth0.inet
```

This allows an update to the interface without a reboot or reloading.

However, the above command changes will be lost after a reboot if the changes in the `/etc/network/interfaces` are not made.

By the way the last answer from BDenis in this list actually works in place of the last command by parsing the `/etc/network/interfaces` file and piping those lines into the command `sudo resolvconf -a eth0`  It's actually half the answer and a really good example of inline sed parsing. If you want to see how it does this just run the first part of the command and watch it parse the `/etc/network/interfaces` file and spit out all the necessary information you need to run the `sudo resolvconf -a eth0` command:

```
sed 's/#.*$//' /etc/network/interfaces | grep dns- | sed 's/dns-//g'
```

Notice this would produce the same out put as the command:

```
echo "nameserver 192.168.3.45
nameserver 192.168.8.10
search example.com"
```

Provided that the `/etc/network/interfaces` file is configured with this information:

```
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.3.3
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.3.1
    dns-search example.com
    dns-nameserver 192.168.3.45 
    dns-nameserver 192.168.8.10
```

Comment: Sadly cannot use that.  My interface is managed by network manager and DHCP, so adding it to `/etc/network/interfaces` is not a valid option in that case.  (Ubuntu 14.04)

Answer (score 1):

On 18.04, the following works reliably (run as root):

```
systemctl stop networking
ip address flush dev <device> # just to be safe
systemctl start networking
```

**Important:** Make sure you have package `resolvconf` installed.
It doesn't seem to be by default, and without it some (!) changes from `/etc/network/interfaces` are silently ignored (e.g. `dns-*`).

Answer (score 1):

On desktop version of Ubuntu 18.04, where there's no service `networking`, and `resolvconf` isn't installed by default, I've succeeded in regenerating `resolv.conf` by restarting `network-manager`:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Comment: For anyone looking at this, network-manager isn't installed "by default" either. So if you're going to install that you might as well install resolvconf too.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
sed -re '/nameservers|dns-search/ !d' -e 's/dns-nameservers/nameserver/' -e 's/dns-search/search/' /etc/network/interfaces  | resolvconf -a eth0.inet && resolvconf -u
```

Adjust accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that if I got rid of the [network] and `generateResolvConf = false` from `/etc/wsl.conf`, shutdown, and restarted, then `/etc/resolv.conf` regenerated without having to do all the reinstall stuff.

Answer (score 0):

My config files were perfect.
I restarted all the necessary services.
I told resolveconf to update.

None of this dynamically updated my resolve.conf and gave me access to my local domain's name servers until I performed a "sudo reboot".

On boot up, resolv.conf was updated and I could ping and get access to a domain name on my manually added dns-nameserver.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

```
nano /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head
nameserver 1.1.1.1
nameserver 1.0.0.1
```

or if that doesn't work, do this instead:

```
nano /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/tail
nameserver 1.1.1.1
nameserver 1.0.0.1
```

Comment: Sorry, this is an English only site.

Answer (score -3):

Also you can try this command:

```
cat /etc/network/interfaces |sed 's/#.*$//'|grep dns-|sed 's/dns-//g'|sudo resolvconf -a eth0.inet
```

Comment: Can you explain why this command should work?

Comment: This does not work correctly if you have more than one nameserver IP in the line `dns-nameserver IP1 IP2`.  The line must then be repeated in `resolv.conf`, but isn't.

Comment: Moreover, `/etc/network/interfaces` uses `dns-nameservers` (notice the `s` at the end) while `resolvconf` uses `nameserver`. The command does not deal with it. And even if everything was correct, the pipeline `sed | grep | sed` definitely wouldn’t be the most efficient way.