# Where to set my DNS on Ubuntu 64 bits?

Tags: dns

On Ubuntu 32 bits I decalred my DNS in `/etc/resolv.conf`
Now that I installed Ubuntu 64 bits I do not find this file.

I edited `/etc/network/interfaces` and `/etc/hosts` but there is no `/etc/resolv.conf`.

So I went to the network manager and I set everything graphically there. But when I run:`sudo service network - interface restart INTERFACE = eth0` I still can not `ping www.google.fr`

Where can I find the equivalent file for `resolv.conf` in order to declare my DNS ? What can I do to connect ? Must I deleted my files editions since I did the settings graphically using the `Network Manager` ?

Comment: You set your DNS in the graphical tool, network manager.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing/Setting DNS settings on boot](http://askubuntu.com/questions/336120/changing-setting-dns-settings-on-boot)

Comment: @bodhi.zazen: no, it is not a duplicated question. Your link shows resolv.conf and that is my problem as I mentioned through my question: I do not find it.

Comment: Read the answer closer, it does not suggest you edit resolv.conf .

Comment: Here is a picture of how to set your DNS with network manager - http://i.stack.imgur.com/Cumpo.png

Comment: @bodhi.zazen: Thank you, but how can I access to it ?

Comment: @bodhi.zazen: sorry for asking, I found it. Thank you

Comment: It is not a problem asking for help. The way askubuntu works is that duplicate questions will be closed to reduce duplication of effort. You did not do anything wrong and we all get frustrated when we are having problems.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen: when I add the address of my DNS, the ésave" button is inactive, so I can not save my DNS.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? Sounds like a bug, you may have to file a bug report and follow the first link I gave you as a work around.

Comment: I edited the settings on the wrong area. Now I saved my DNS. However when i restart network-interface, I still am not able to connect. I will edit my question

Comment: restart network-manager: `sudo service network-manager restart`

Comment: I run sudo service network-manager restart but still can not ping 8.8.8.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the initial link I gave you did not work,

```
sudo gedit /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head
```

Add your nameserver(s) , for example

> nameserver 8.8.8.8
>
> nameserver 8.8.4.4

save your changes and close gedit

Then run

```
sudo resolvconf -u
```

Comment: Thank you a lot !!!!!! It works ! You are the God of Linux ! Regards