# Apache server - domain name return "404 Not Found"

Tags: server, apache2, virtualhost

When I try to reach the site with my IP it works fine but when I try to use my domain name to connect I get "404 Not Found".
I am on Ubuntu Server 16.04.1 LTS

**/etc/hosts/**

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       zbytki.cz
127.0.1.1       zbytki.cz
192.168.123.106 zbytki.cz
```

**/etc/apache2/sites-available/zbytki.cz.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@zbytki.cz
    ServerName zbytki.cz
    ServerAlias www.zbytki.cz
    DirectoryIndex index.html
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/zbytki.cz/public_html
    LogLevel warn
    ErrorLog /var/www/html/zbytki.cz/log/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/html/zbytki.cz/log/access.log combined
    <Directory "/var/www/html/zbytki.cz/public_html">
          Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**/etc/hostname**

```
zbytki.cz
```

**/etc/apache2/apache2.conf**

```
...
Timeout 300
...
KeepAlive Off
...
HostnameLookups Off
...
LogLevel warn
...    
AccessFileName .htaccess
...
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
     StartServers 4
     MinSpareServers 20
     MaxSpareServers 40
     MaxClients 200
     MaxRequestsPerChild 4500
</IfModule>
```

**/etc/apache2/ports.conf**

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
Listen 80
...
```

If you need more information just ask.
Can someone please help me ?

Comment: Is `$ a2ensite zbytki.cz.conf` applied?

Comment: yes, site zbytki.cz already enabled

Comment: Did you try to use incognito browser window? I think it should work if you call it up from the same pc. Sometimes previous not successful attempts remains in browser cache.

Comment: I cleared cache in firefox, it doesnt fix my problem.

Comment: I concluded that you are trying to open `http://zbytki.cz` (`http://192.168.123.106`) by second PC from your local network - is that true?

Comment: If the answer is yes - just for a test, try to open the host address from the server directly. In the terminal, you can use **lynx**: `$ sudo apt install lynx`; `lynx zbytki.cz`.

Comment: I have two virtual machines, ubuntu server (bridged adapter) and ubuntu desktop (NAT and Host-only networking). I am trying to open Server domain name from dektop.

Comment: Ok, right! I think yours configuration is OK, but what is the result of `$ lynx zbytki.cz`, executed from server's console?

Comment: It works shows Hello World!!! but when I try with alias www.zbytki.cz It doesnt work shows message: "This site requires Cookies and Javascript enabled please change your browser settings or upgrade your browser".

Comment: If you add `127.0.1.1 www.zbytki.cz` in `/etc/hosts` it will work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your web server's configuration is OK. To access certain *host* via *host name*, instead of IP-address, you must have pre-configured Domain Name Service / Server ([DNS](https://help.ubuntu.com/18.04/serverguide/dns.html)). There is two solutions:

**1st**. If you want you can configure yours own DNS which you can use in your local network. Here you go [the manual](https://help.ubuntu.com/18.04/serverguide/dns-installation.html) - look at [Primary Master](https://help.ubuntu.com/18.04/serverguide/dns-configuration.html#dns-primarymaster-configuration) configuration.

**2nd**. You can buy (register) a *domain name* from any DNS provider. This *domain* will be accessible from the Internet. For example I bought one from host.bg - there has a promotion of ***.info*** at the moment.

In this case you will need a (public) static IP-adress or pre-configured Dynamic DNS (DDNS), which will connects your dinamic IP-adress with the *domain name*.

---

I've made short survey and I found that domain **zbytki.cz** is registred from someone - hope that is you.

[image]

When I checked with `$ nslookup zbytki.cz` it returns: `** server can't find zbytki.cz: NXDOMAIN`.

So the domain is registered but is not configured to work with certain (static) IP address.