# How do you update the DNS resolver configuration without causing downtime?

Tags: networking, server, dns, resolvconf

### A note

New question, since everything else on this matter appears to be outdated and/or conflicting. Hold your close votes, please :)

### The problem

On stock installs of Ubuntu 12 and 14 Server, the going advice seems to be that the way you make DNS changes is to edit the interfaces file and add the dns- options there. Only problem is, on servers, where uptime is a concern, it appears the only way to force those changes to be be applied is to bounce the affected network interface with `ifdown/ifup`.

I've got a large number of servers to make a set of DNS changes on, and I need to update their resolver configurations, en masse, without toggling the network interfaces in this fashion. I also need to make sure the changes stick after a reboot.

The problem is that all of these servers were built with the dns- options in the `interfaces` file, meaning that if I change `resolvconf`'s `head` or `tail` files, I'll end up with a bunch of duplicate lines on reboot.

The process needs to be something like:

1. Completely eliminate the resolver configuration (it's all over the place right now)
2. Set the options to new, known-good values
3. Save those options so they are used by applications immediately, and so they'll be in place after a reboot.

So, a recap:

### What won't work

- Editing the lines in `interfaces` (requires an outage to recycle the interface)
- Editing resolv.conf directly (won't take effect, won't be saved)
- Editing the resolvconf `head` or `tail` files (won't take effect, will have duplicate lines on reboot)

### The actual question

Is there a way to effect a change like this, *without* interrupting service? Ideally, I could force resolvconf to go through its update process without toggling the interface.

Comment: "Editing resolv.conf directly (won't take effect" - why won't it take effect, exactly? And what's the problem with having duplicate entries until reboot? Only the last `search` entry takes effect and multiple `nameserver` entries shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Mostly because it's going to be a mess for automation going forward. I was under the impression that just messing around in resolv.conf will lead to a not-fully-working resolver, since the resolvconf package handles a notification mechanism of some kind. Is this not the case?

Comment: "Messing around" will obviously cause problems. This is what I'd do: Use `sed` to delete entries in `interfaces`, add `resolvconf.d/base` or `resolvconf.d/tail`, run `resolvconf -u` and ignore the duplicate entries (which will go away next reboot/network cycle anyway).

Comment: Anything that parses resolv.conf will be confused by the dupe lines, not just the resolver itself. (Example: Augeas). Ideally those could be removed - where is resolvconf pulling that info from?

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/a/225100/158442

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you absolutely can't have `resolv.conf` be in an inconsistent state, here's what I did:

1. The "state" of the resolver generated from the `dns-` lines in your `/etc/network/interfaces` is stored in `/var/run/resolvconf/interface/(interfacename).inet` - this file was truncated.
2. The same data (`search`, `nameserver`, etc, same stuff that's in a completed `resolv.conf`) was copied into `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/tail` (the `tail` file had to be created), with an appropriate comment added so anybody that comes along later can see what happened.
3. The `dns` lines in `/etc/network/interfaces` were commented out
4. And finally run `resolvconf -u` to regenerate the `/etc/resolv.conf` from the tail file

This has the effect of:

- Decoupling the resolver settings from the network interface (which if you're on a single interface box is needlessly annoying)
- Placing the resolver settings in a single purpose text file (the `tail` file)
- Making the changes take effect immediately
- ..and having them persist after a reboot
- And re-generating the system wide `/etc/resolv.conf` with `resolvconf`'s notification mechanism intact.
- ...with no downtime :D